# how to select image src using PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

So i have some images with several forms like this :

```
<a href="" class="link-img" alt="">
  <img editable="true" style="display: block; cursor: default;" class="main-image" 
    width="538" height="auto" src="src" alt="large image">
</a>
```

and like this :

```
<a href="" class="link link-img">
 <img src="src" style="width: 100%; display: block; cursor: pointer;" editable="true" 
  class="main-image imageLink" width="" height="auto" alt="">
</a>
```

so my code to select the src image is :

```
$c = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+)" class="link link-img" alt="(.+)"><img src="(.+)"><\/a>/i'
,'<% link url="$1" caption="<img style=max-width:500px; src=$8 >" html="true" %>',$c);
```

i tried that several times but the code doesn't worked, so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Comment: To extract data from HTML, use an HTML parser and not some regexp.

Comment: You need to use something like [PHPDomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: but i need that in server side

Comment: Good thing PHPDomDocument isn't for use on the client side then

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to grab `src` from image `src="([^"]+)"`

[image]

[image]

**EDIT :** see regex here https://www.regex101.com/r/yF8tJ1/1

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
$re = "/src=\"([^\"]+)\"/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"\" class=\"link-img\" alt=\"\">\n  <img editable=\"true\" style=\"display: block; cursor: default;\" class=\"main-image\" \n    width=\"538\" height=\"auto\" src=\"src\" alt=\"large image\">\n</a>\n\n<a href=\"\" class=\"link link-img\">\n <img src=\"src\" style=\"width: 100%; display: block; cursor: pointer;\" editable=\"true\" \n  class=\"main-image imageLink\" width=\"\" height=\"auto\" alt=\"\">\n</a>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I suggest a different regex. `/src=((['"]?)(?:[^\2]|\2+)*\2)/g`. This one matches broken HTML attributes as close as I can get to the behavior of HTML/XML parsers.

Comment: Actually, use `/src=((['"]?)(?:[^\2]|\2+)+?\2/gi`. This one works properly. An input like `<img src="test">` will match `src="test"`, `<img src="test"" >` will match `src="test""` and `<img src='test""/><span>My new 'test'</span><img src='55'>` will match `src='test""/><span>My new '` and `src='55`.

Comment: Sorry for flooding this! I've made a new regex: `src=([^"'>]+|(['"]?)(?:[^\2]|\2+)+?\2)`. This one works now with `<img src=55>`, which matches `src=55`.

Comment: Just trying to make the impossible. Some people would get really angry with such regex. But hey, it works!