# How to get all of attributes with regex?

Tags: php, regex, attributes

I made this regex to get all attributes in tag "img".

```
 /<img\s+(?:([a-z_-]+)\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*)*\s*\/>/g
```

But, It just take only one attribute which is last.

How can I get all attributes with regex?

Test String:

```
 <img src="abc.png" alt="abc" />
 <img alt="def" src="def.png" />
 <img src="abc.png" alt="abc" style="border:none" />
 <img alt="def" src="def.png" style="border:none" />
```

Result: (with http://www.regex101.com)

```
 MATCH 1
 1. [19-22] `alt`
 2. [24-27] `abc`

 MATCH 2
 1. [47-50] `src`
 2. [52-59] `def.png`

 MATCH 3
 1. [93-98] `style`
 2. [100-111]   `border:none`

 MATCH 4
 1. [145-150]   `style`
 2. [152-163]   `border:none`
```

Comment: Just take the DOM parser.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use `\G` anchor in-order to do a continuous string match.

```
(?:<img|(?<!^)\G)\h*([\w-]+)="([^"]*)"(?=.*?\/>)
```

Get the attribute from group index 1 and get the value from group index 2.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/3)

```
$string = <<<EOT
 <img src="abc.png" alt="abc" />
 <img alt="def" src="def.png" />
 <img src="abc.png" alt="abc" style="border:none" />
 <img alt="def" src="def.png" style="border:none" />
EOT;
preg_match_all('~(?:<img|(?<!^)\G)\h*(\w+)="([^"]+)"(?=.*?\/>)~', $string, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
print_r($match[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => src
    [1] => alt
    [2] => alt
    [3] => src
    [4] => src
    [5] => alt
    [6] => style
    [7] => alt
    [8] => src
    [9] => style
)
Array
(
    [0] => abc.png
    [1] => abc
    [2] => def
    [3] => def.png
    [4] => abc.png
    [5] => abc
    [6] => border:none
    [7] => def
    [8] => def.png
    [9] => border:none
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work with data attributes like `data-` or even `src-set`. Don't avoid `-` character.

Comment: @hosein simple, add `-` inside the first capturing group https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/27

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/(\w+)=["']([a-zA-Z0-9_.:'"]+)["']/
```

Remember if you are using this with php option g is not supported, use preg_match_all() function

Try it at: https://regex101.com/r/cQ8jT2/1

Comment: As a side note, you might want to use something like `/([\w\-]+)=([^"'>]+|(['"]?)(?:[^\3]|\3+)+?\3)/` which matches `attr=value`, `attr='value'`, `attr=' value "value" '`, `attr="value"`, `attr="regex 'r' us"`, `attr="another ""`, `attr="different delimiters' match until one valid is found[...]` and a few different combinations. But it might not work. If was addapted from my comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988667/how-to-select-image-src-using-php/27988904?noredirect=1#comment44369639_27988904) in another answer. You can check it working here: https://regex101.com/r/sT9rT8/1

Comment: Also, you can't use `(\w+)` in the first group since `data-value` won't match. Use `([\w\-]+)` instead.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, I tried to edit the other comment but it is too late. The real working regex is this: `([\w\-]+)=([^"'> ]+|(['"]?)(?:[^\3]|\3+)+?\3)` and you can check here: https://regex101.com/r/sT9rT8/2

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel In `[a-zA-Z0-9_.':"]` if you add a space it will take care of all following cases you mentioned except `attr=value`.  regex `(\w+)=["']([a-zA-Z0-9_.:'" ]+)["']` will match `attr='value', attr=' value "value" ', attr="value", attr="regex 'r' us", attr="another "", attr="different delimiters'`

Comment: The regex you provided isn't working properly. You can see the workings here: https://regex101.com/r/fF0dH6/1 which is failing for things like `style="font-size:15px"` and even `style="dorber:none;"`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The solution I've provided works regardless of the tag. One can extract the `<img>` tags and process later.